# XSLT 1.0: Group by attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

I have the following simplified XML data and I want to group it by the Category:

```
<Root>
    <Rows>
        <Row>
            <Column name="Title" Value="Document 1"/>
            <Column name="Category" Value="Category 1"/>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Column name="Title" Value="Document 2"/>
            <Column name="Category" Value="Category 2"/>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Column name="Title" Value="Document 3"/>
            <Column name="Category" Value="Category 1"/>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Column name="Title" Value="Document 4"/>
            <Column name="Category" Value="Category 2"/>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Column name="Title" Value="Document 5"/>
            <Column name="Category" Value="Category 3"/>
        </Row>
    </Rows>
</Root>
```

And I expect the following result:

**Category 1**

- Document 1
- Document 3

**Category 2**

- Document 2
- Document 4

**Category 3**

- Document 5

I already tried it with Muenchian grouping because I can only use XSLT 1.0 , but there's no output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output indent="no" method="html"/>

  <xsl:key name="groups" match="/Rows/Row" use="Column[name='Category']/@Value"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', Column)[1])]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row">
    <h1>
      <xsl:value-of select="Column[name='Category']/@Value"/>
    </h1>

    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', Column[name='Category']/@Value)">
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="Column[name='Title']/@Value"/>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I didn't find a solution to group by an attribute where the name is another attribute. Where's my fault, or is there a better solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the fact that `<Root>` is your top level tag. Please, try: `<xsl:key name="groups" match="/Root/Rows/Row" use="Column[name='Category']/@Value"/>` and `<xsl:template match="/Root">`.

Comment: Maybe this is another issue but this didn't solve the problem. There's still no output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output indent="no" method="html"/>

  <xsl:key name="groups" match="Row" use="Column[@name='Category']/@Value"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/Rows/Row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', Column/@Value)[1])]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row">
    <h1>
      <xsl:value-of select="Column[@name='Category']/@Value"/>
    </h1>

    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', Column[@name='Category']/@Value)">
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="Column[@name='Title']/@Value"/>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```